# Select a distinct value count and the value it's self 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to receive the distinct cost from my db, also the count for that distinct cost. I am getting the 'DISTINCT COST' back but not the 'COST' which I am gonna need to run my next process. Can somebody help me just return the DISTINCT COST itself along with the count?

```
 $sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COST) AS COSTQ FROM STATS WHERE PURCHASEID = ".$purchaseid;
       $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $costcoun = $row['COSTQ'];
                $cost = $row['COST']; // I have already tried ['DISTINCT COST'] which i had no luck with either.
              // This is where I run my next process
                  }
                 } else {
                      echo "0 results";
                 }
```

Comment: You haven't retrieved `COST` column yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` clause is designed for this situation exactly - it breaks the query up to distinct values, and applies aggregate functions on each group separately:

```sql
SELECT   cost, 
         COUNT(*) AS costq -- No need for distinct, GROUP BY handles it
FROM     stats
WHERE    purchaseid = 'something'
GROUP BY cost
```

Comment: This works!! Thank You 8-) On a side note that was my first time using or needing the Group By function.